# Sideload an App with Tenant Admin permissions

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, deployment, app

I just read the following, regarding a issue we have on SharePoint Server 2019, with an app we can't trust if it requires tenant admin permissions (even if the account we use has full admin rights)

> registering app principle for a tenant full control app won't be possible as you need to have an app which go through approval process by tenant admin.
>   the issue is even if you are  a tenant admin the trust button will be always disabled.
>   The work around is to create a sharepoint add-in .app file and upload it to your app catalog then the approval process will kick in and you can then use your clienID and secret in your apponly scenario

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1940f20b-bd99-490f-b620-6c1e9dcd473d/your-tenant-administrator-has-to-approve-this-app?forum=appsforsharepoint)

My question is : is it a bug or is it by design ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tenant level permissions with app-only can only be granted via trusting it against your tenant administration site.

Refer to this article for more:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/development-experience-tenant-apponly-permissions-in-sharepoint-online